# How to keep a Jquery drop down menu down?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I can't figure out how to make the menu stay down when I move the mouse off the button and onto the actual menu. I'm using the jquery slidedown function.

```
<script>
function drop(elid) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elid);
    $(element).slideDown("fast");
}

function raise(elid) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elid);
    $(element).slideUp("fast");
}
 </script>
```

The HTML look kind of like this.

```
<a href="menu.php" onMouseOver="drop('drop_down')" onMouseOut="raise('drop_down')">Click Here</a>

<div id="drop_down">Menu</div>
```

The actual link to the site is albionsteakhouse.com if this doesn't make sense. I want the menu to stay down when the mouse is on it. What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Use `mouseenter` and `moouseleave` events or jQuery `hover` method instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `$(element).slideDown` you sholud try `$(element).show();`